# project-Swift.h compiler errors

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

Im having an issue with the auto-generated Project-Swift.h file when I try to import it.

In the -Swift.h file:

```
    SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC7ProjectName20InviteToComposer")
@interface InviteToComposer : NSObject <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate *>
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithRecipient:(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull)recipient name:(NSString * _Nonnull)name OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController * _Nonnull)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;
@end
```

when attempting to compile, i get two errors from this class:

```
"unknown type name 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'; did you mean 'MFMessageComposeViewController'?
```

and "expected a type" in regards to "`(MessageComposeResult)`"

I tried including @nonobjc in front of the class and function names so that it wouldn't include them in the -Swift.h file, but apparently you can't do that to a class and the function itself that has the error gives me
`"Type 'InviteToComposer' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'"` then states `"protocol is not @objc but requires it."`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift error: “Cannot find interface declaration for 'SKScene', superclass of”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809938/swift-error-cannot-find-interface-declaration-for-skscene-superclass-of).  swiftc is failing to add `@import MessageUI;` to the -Swift.h.

Comment: hey Brian, i checked out that link, but when i imported SpriteKit like they said, it did nothing. Any ideas? Were you saying i should import message to my bridging header? mind clarifying for me?

Comment: You should import the missing framework in your bridging header.  In your case it is `@import MessageUI;`

Comment: @Grant_E Hi, have you fixed that?

Answer (score 2):

In your -swift add @protocol MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate before your class declaration.

It's an apple "you probably should be using swift/we don't care enough about you to fix it" thing.

Also thing with my fix is that every time you clean the project or switch a build device, it will clear up the code and you have to add it again.

A permeant workaround is create a sub protocol of the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate in objective-c and reference it from there.